# Error (415) adding host to SCVMM 2012

Tags: system-center

We are trying to add a host to SCVMM 2012.
But the scvmm server can't access the Admin$ share of the host. And it throws the following error and warning:

**Error (415)**

Agent installation failed copying C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012\Virtual Machine Manager\agents\I386\3.0.6005.0\msiInstaller.exe to \Host.FQDN\ADMIN$\msiInstaller.exe.
The network path was not found

Recommended Action

1. Ensure Host.FQDN is online and not blocked by a firewall.
2. Ensure that file and printer sharing is enabled on Host.FQDN and it not blocked by a firewall.
3. Ensure that there is sufficient free space on the system volume.
4. Verify that the ADMIN$ share on Host.FQDN exists. If the ADMIN$ share does not exist, reboot server. and then try the operation again.

**Warning (10444)**

The VMM management server was unable to impersonate the supplied credentials.

Recommended Action
To add a host in a disjointed domain namespace, ensure that the credentials are valid and of a domain account. In addition, the SCVMMService must run as the local system account or a domain account with sufficient privileges to be able to impersonate other users.

But the admin$ of another server in the same data center can be accessed by the SCVMM server.

More info:
I have checked the Admin$ is enable on the host.

From the scvmm server, run the following command failed:

```
winrm id -r:HOST.FQDN
```

> WSManFault
>       Message = Access is denied.
>
> Error number:  -2147024891 0x80070005 Access is denied.

But it is successful on another server in the same data center.

Could anyone give some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, the issue is caused by company security policy.
The host server is in country A' data center.
The TFS server and SCVMM are in country B's data center.
All the servers are domain trusted.

But for data transfer policy of the country, the file share is disabled for all servers, except some public server which is audited by IT for file share.
That's why some server(public server)'s Admin$ can be accessed in country B.

At last, we decide to move the SCVMM server to country A's data center, in the same data center with the Hosts.

Comment: Here a useful post who has the same issue but different cause, VLAN.[link](http://nukeitmike.com/blog/2013/05/06/error-415-adding-a-host-to-scvmm-2012-sp1/)